# public/private variable declaration with run-time function in it

Tags: php

I am trying to set a `public/private` (doesn't matter) variable (array) in a class

in such way (very stripped)

```
class Test extends Whatever
{

    private $rules = array(
        'folder' => 'files/game/pictures/' . date('Ymd'), //this line causes error mentioned below
    );

    public function __construct() {//some code}

}
```

and it gives me an error

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'`

why? I declare arrays like this all the time and without problem.

---

**Solution** : first comment below the question.

Comment: `declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated. ` [Object Properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) - that includes the results from function calls

Comment: oh thanks, I was looking for this doc over an hour

Answer (score 0):

Please, try:

```
class Test extends Whatever {

    private $rules;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->rules = array(
            'folder' => 'files/game/pictures/' . date('Ymd'), //this line causes error mentioned below
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: As soon as I saw 1st [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933728/public-private-variable-declaration-with-run-time-function-in-it/18933809?noredirect=1#comment27956773_18933728), I knew the answer, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Class declared vars are not using array's (it's an object).
Try this:

```
class Test extends Whatever {

    private $rules = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->rules = array('folder' => 'files/game/pictures/' . date('Ymd'));
        // Other code...
    }
}
```

Comment: As soon as I saw 1st [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933728/public-private-variable-declaration-with-run-time-function-in-it/18933809?noredirect=1#comment27956773_18933728), I knew the answer, but thanks.